# Can't set PHP settings for Azure Linux App Service

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, php-8

I am trying to set some things for PHP 8.0.3 in a **LINUX** App Service in Azure.   I placed the following in my .htaccess but the settings seems to be ignored.

```
php_value memory_limit 2048M
php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
php_value post_max_size 256M
php_value max_execution_time 3600
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value output_buffering Off
```

After restarting the App Service, and checking phpinfo() I get:

| Directive | Local Value | Master Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| memory_limit | 128M | 128M |
| post_max_size | 8M | 8M |

I saw a post about creating a settings.ini and I tried that.   The settings for that seemed to take, but then that broke the mysqli setup.   So it seems to completely overwrite all settings instead of augmenting the ones I need.

Any ideas?

Obviously my WordPress site is choking on 128M of RAM.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Linux PHP v8 blessed images are defaulted to [nginx/php-fpm](https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/nginx-fpm), so you may not need .htaccess. However, you may try with rewrite rules to mimic .htaccess.

You can configure using startup command.
[Azure App Service on Linux FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/faq-app-service-linux#what-are-the-expected-values-for-the-startup-file-section-when-i-configure-the-runtime-stack-)

Additionally,

Official support for PHP 8 will only be available on Linux, as a result of this App Service will only support PHP 8 on Apps Service Linux instances.
See these docs:
[php_support](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/Runtime_Support/php_support.md#php-8)